# Get the results of previous tests

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to get the results of previous tests in pytest? Or drop test execution if a few specific test failure?

for example:

```
pytest.mark.skipif(test_failed("test1", "test2"), reason="Reason")
def test_the_unknown(): pass
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing builtin for that kind of behavior atm

but its possible to create tools for that as plugins,
if you are up to it, please get in touch on github, the ml or the irc channels